# Inversion of control - XML or Fluent API?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I've just started using Inversion of Control containers and I'm having a difficult time understanding when to use the fluent API or XML when configuring and registering components.

Are there any best practices around when you should prefer one over the other?  Or is this simply developer preference?  Would it be considered bad practice to mix them in a simple application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sweet spot for me is a combination of the two. XML for pulling together large units of functionality and possibly configuring them at deployment time; fluent for setting up the individual components within those units. See http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/StructuringWithModules for an Autofac example. Other containers often have similar capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Container configuration in code (what you call "the fluent API") is more maintainable, because the code is compiled and therefore the compiler will find many errors for you. However, it requires you to recompile if you want to make changes.

Container configuration in XML is the opposite: the compiler cannot help you find errors, but you can make changes without recompiling.

If you are just starting out with dependency injection, I would stick to configuration in code to keep things simple.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the other answers don't touch on a very important problem the Fluent Configuration brings to you DI implementation. Which is hard-wiring concrete implementations to your code base, thus creating tightly-coupled dependencies...which ironically is what IoC Containers are trying to solve. You will find yourself contaminating all your applications with component registration code, now, that doesn't sound good.

Why doesn't it sound good? Because when you have a distributed system with many applications that use different components you basically have two options to register your components:

### 1. Add DI code on all your applications.

Something like this...

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<ConsoleLogger>().As<ILogger>();
builder.RegisterType<EmailNotificationDispatcher>().As<INotificationDispatcher>();
builder.RegisterType<DefaultMessageHandler>().As<IMessageHandler>();
//many more...
```

and of course, ALL the applications in the system will need this sort of logic with different components.

#### Advantage

You're using Fluent Configuration because it is pretty...that's about it :)

#### Disadvantage

- You are contaminating all you're applications with this fluent component registration, including CONCRETE types
- You will need to recompile your application(s) if you need to swap out a dependency/component
- If you need to migration to different IoC container tool...the same

### 2. Wrap your DI code inside a wrapper component to make your applications IoC-container-agnostic.

Something like this...

```
public sealed class ComponentFactory
{
    private static IContainer _container;

    public static void Init()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<ConsoleLogger>().As<ILogger>();
        builder.RegisterType<EmailNotificationDispatcher>().As<INotificationDispatcher>();
        builder.RegisterType<DefaultMessageHandler>().As<IMessageHandler>();
        //many more...
        _container = builder.Build();
    }

    public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return _container.Resolve<T>();
    }
}
```

With this approach your applications won't effectively be aware of what concrete classes their using at all.
You don't need to re-compile and redeploy all applications if you need to swap components.
Furthermore, if you need to migrate to a different IoC Container, the changes will be done in one place...the wrapper class.
The huge disadvange of this approach is that you will have to deploy all components to all applications bin folder even if there are components (or binaries assemblies) one application might not need. So, your lightweight applications will become fat heavy clients.

### XML (or json) Configuration

With xml configuration none of the above will happen...

- you deploy what your applications need...on a per-application basis
- you register the components your applications need...on a per-app basis
- your applications are light and have no idea of what concrete implementation they're using. They become very scalable
- there's more but hopefully you're getting the idea

Now, I'm not an advocate of XML Configuration, I hate it, I'm a coder and prefer the fluent way over xml (or json) but in my experience xml/json configuration proves to be more scalable and maintainable.

Now, shoot me!!!